# Cannot GRANT privileges as root

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-5.1

Because of having some problems, I decided to re-create all users except for `root@localhost`. This works fine, but the newly created user has no right to do anything. What I want is to simply give all rights to root at some local IP. I (as `root@localhost`) tried

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'10.0.3.210';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.0.3.210';
```

The first command works, the second one fails with the message

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I don't get why `root@localhost` can't do everything, I'm sure I didn't mess with its privileges. From

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost'
```

I get

```
Grants for root@localhost
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

whatever this means. Am I missing a needed privilege? Can it be fixed?

I'm working with mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.61, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64).

Comment: Have you tried individual permissions eg `GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.0.3.210';`?

Comment: Now I have and it works with SELECT and UPDATE; I'm gonna try them all now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oh my goodness, I think the problem stems from mixing the mysql schema of different mysql versions. First of all, run this query:

```
desc mysql.user;
```

For MySQL 8.0, you get 51 columns

```
mysql> desc mysql.user;
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Host | char(255) | NO | PRI |  |  |
| User | char(32) | NO | PRI |  |  |
| Select_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Insert_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Update_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Delete_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Create_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Drop_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Reload_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Shutdown_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Process_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| File_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Grant_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| References_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Index_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Alter_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Show_db_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Super_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Create_tmp_table_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Lock_tables_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Execute_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Repl_slave_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Repl_client_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Create_view_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Show_view_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Create_routine_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Alter_routine_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Create_user_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Event_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Trigger_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Create_tablespace_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| ssl_type | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO |  |  |  |
| ssl_cipher | blob | NO |  | NULL |  |
| x509_issuer | blob | NO |  | NULL |  |
| x509_subject | blob | NO |  | NULL |  |
| max_questions | int unsigned | NO |  | 0 |  |
| max_updates | int unsigned | NO |  | 0 |  |
| max_connections | int unsigned | NO |  | 0 |  |
| max_user_connections | int unsigned | NO |  | 0 |  |
| plugin | char(64) | NO |  | caching_sha2_password |  |
| authentication_string | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| password_expired | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| password_last_changed | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |
| password_lifetime | smallint unsigned | YES |  | NULL |  |
| account_locked | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Create_role_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Drop_role_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO |  | N |  |
| Password_reuse_history | smallint unsigned | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Password_reuse_time | smallint unsigned | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Password_require_current | enum('N','Y') | YES |  | NULL |  |
| User_attributes | json | YES |  | NULL |  |

51 rows in set (0.00 sec)

For MySQL 5.6, you get 43 columns

```
mysql> desc mysql.user;
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Host                   | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| User                   | char(16)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Password               | char(41)                          | NO   |     |         |       |
| Select_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Insert_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Update_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Delete_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Drop_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Reload_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Shutdown_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Process_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| File_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Grant_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| References_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Index_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_db_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Super_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv  | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Lock_tables_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Execute_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_slave_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_client_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_view_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_view_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_routine_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_routine_priv     | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_user_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Event_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Trigger_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tablespace_priv | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| ssl_type               | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |         |       |
| ssl_cipher             | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_issuer            | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_subject           | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| max_questions          | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_updates            | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_connections        | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_user_connections   | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| plugin                 | char(64)                          | YES  |     |         |       |
| authentication_string  | text                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password_expired       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
43 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

For MySQL 5.5, you get 42 columns

```
mysql> desc mysql.user;
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Host                   | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| User                   | char(16)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Password               | char(41)                          | NO   |     |         |       |
| Select_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Insert_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Update_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Delete_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Drop_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Reload_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Shutdown_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Process_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| File_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Grant_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| References_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Index_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_db_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Super_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv  | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Lock_tables_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Execute_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_slave_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_client_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_view_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_view_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_routine_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_routine_priv     | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_user_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Event_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Trigger_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tablespace_priv | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| ssl_type               | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |         |       |
| ssl_cipher             | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_issuer            | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_subject           | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| max_questions          | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_updates            | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_connections        | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_user_connections   | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| plugin                 | char(64)                          | YES  |     |         |       |
| authentication_string  | text                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
42 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

For MySQL 5.1, you get 39 columns

```
mysql> desc mysql.user;
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type                              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Host                  | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| User                  | char(16)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Password              | char(41)                          | NO   |     |         |       |
| Select_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Insert_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Update_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Delete_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Drop_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Reload_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Shutdown_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Process_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| File_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Grant_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| References_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Index_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_db_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Super_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Lock_tables_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Execute_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_slave_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_client_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_view_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_view_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_routine_priv   | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_routine_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_user_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Event_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Trigger_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| ssl_type              | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |         |       |
| ssl_cipher            | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_issuer           | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_subject          | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| max_questions         | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_updates           | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_connections       | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_user_connections  | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
39 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

For MySQL 5.0, you get 37 columns

```
mysql> desc mysql.user;
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type                              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Host                  | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| User                  | char(16)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Password              | char(41)                          | NO   |     |         |       |
| Select_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Insert_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Update_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Delete_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Drop_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Reload_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Shutdown_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Process_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| File_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Grant_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| References_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Index_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_db_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Super_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Lock_tables_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Execute_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_slave_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_client_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_view_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_view_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_routine_priv   | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_routine_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_user_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| ssl_type              | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |         |       |
| ssl_cipher            | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_issuer           | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_subject          | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| max_questions         | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_updates           | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_connections       | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_user_connections  | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
37 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

For MySQL 4.x, you get 31 columns

```
mysql> desc mysql.user;
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type                              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Host                  | varchar(60) binary                |      | PRI |         |       |
| User                  | varchar(16) binary                |      | PRI |         |       |
| Password              | varchar(16) binary                |      |     |         |       |
| Select_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Insert_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Update_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Delete_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Create_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Drop_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Reload_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Shutdown_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Process_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| File_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Grant_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| References_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Index_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Alter_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Show_db_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Super_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Lock_tables_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Execute_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Repl_slave_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| Repl_client_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     |      |     | N       |       |
| ssl_type              | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') |      |     |         |       |
| ssl_cipher            | blob                              |      |     |         |       |
| x509_issuer           | blob                              |      |     |         |       |
| x509_subject          | blob                              |      |     |         |       |
| max_questions         | int(11) unsigned                  |      |     | 0       |       |
| max_updates           | int(11) unsigned                  |      |     | 0       |       |
| max_connections       | int(11) unsigned                  |      |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
31 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Picture this scenario:

- You install 5.0
- You uninstall 5.0
- You forgot to move /var/lib/mysql out of the way
- You install 5.1

The user permissions start getting shifted. Whenever you run `SHOW GRANTS;`, it is hardwired to expect columns in specfic places in mysql.user (given the fact that mysql.user is a MyISAM and its ROW_FORMAT is Dynamic (Default)). It is very easy to see a user suddenly lose permissions when you reload a MySQL 5.0 version of mysql.user into a MySQL 5.1 instance.

In the future, should you ever decide to reload users into MySQL, try to dump the users to a text file using [**pt-show-grants**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-show-grants.html) rather than mysqldump.

I actually wrote my own version of pt-show-grants as follows:

```
mysql -hhostaddr -umyuserid -pmypassword --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -hhostaddr -umyuserid -pmypassword --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

This will produce all user grants as SQL, which is far more portable than standard mysql techniques. Simply reload the SQL script and the GRANTS are executed. Of course, such reloading is only forward compatible, never backward.

Comment: That's right the problem I had today. It cost me 4 hours to figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

The comment by `gbn` brought me to the solution: No idea how it came, but `root@localhost` was lacking some privileges. So first obtain them all via

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET XXX_priv = 'Y' WHERE user = 'root' AND host = 'localhost'
```

There are quite a few columns, so using something like

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat(' ', column_name, '=\'Y\''))
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = 'mysql'
  AND table_name = 'user'
  AND column_name LIKE '%_priv'
```

can save quite some typing. Probably `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` is needed after the UPDATEs. Once I have all privileges, I can also GRANT them.

Comment: there is lots of xxx_priv , is there any solution to update them all at once with a simple command?

Comment: @alex Use the SELECT from my answer to get the long part of the query as a string. You could add one more concat to get the whole query.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen an issue where you can't `GRANT CREATE TABLESPACE`.

However, I'm not sure of all details and I saw it on 5.5/Solaris

My comment above and your response indicates that this may apply here. That is, you can GRANT everything except `CREATE TABLESPACE` permissions

Comment: I've never heard about "GRANT CREATE TABLESPACE" and can't see it [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges) either.

Comment: @maaartinus: must be in 5.5 only then http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

Comment: Maybe you yourself were lacking the privilege? See my answer.

Comment: @maaartinus: no, there is some bug or issue with it. I was SUPER. Anyway, glad to have assisted

Answer (score 1):

Like [@RolandoMYSQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16441) correctly stated this issue is due to upgrading your MySQL version while still keeping older files around (without dumping / restoring). [@gbn](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16403) also correctly concluded that this is related to the `CREATE TABLESPACE` privilege that got added in MySQL 5.5. You probably have database files from MySQL 5.1.

The simple solution (that is also documented in [MySQL’s reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)) is to run `mysql_upgrade` while eventually skipping the `GRANT` tables check:

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
mysql_upgrade
```