# set a lower privilege permission on a specific database when a GRANT ALL exists on a pattern matching this database on MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a user which has access (`GRANT ALL`) to a set of databases matching a wildcard pattern, now I would like to remove one specific database matching this wildcard from it's access.

```sql
mysql> select * from mysql.db where host='server' AND user='user' and Db LIKE 'db_%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 Host: server
                   Db: db_%
                 User: db
          Select_priv: Y
          Insert_priv: Y
          Update_priv: Y
          Delete_priv: Y
          Create_priv: Y
            Drop_priv: Y
           Grant_priv: N
      References_priv: Y
           Index_priv: Y
           Alter_priv: Y
Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
     Lock_tables_priv: Y
     Create_view_priv: Y
       Show_view_priv: Y
  Create_routine_priv: Y
   Alter_routine_priv: Y
         Execute_priv: Y
           Event_priv: Y
         Trigger_priv: Y
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've tried to revoke access on this specific database but that does not work because that does not match a existing rule I assume

```
mysql> REVOKE ALL on db_6.* FROM 'user'@'server';                               
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'user' on host 'server'
```

eventually I granted the lowest permission (`USAGE`) for this specific database.

```
mysql> show grants for 'user'@'server';
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user@server                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_%`.* TO 'user'@'server'    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
mysql> GRANT USAGE on db_6.* to 'user'@'server';
mysql> show grants for 'user'@'server';
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user@server                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'server'                  |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_%`.* TO 'user'@'server'    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

is there a way to achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: Grants system in MySQL uses the rules literally (i.e. you may revoke only those privilege which was granted previously literally). And none permission set on some level can be revoked/blocked on lower level. If you grant ALL to db_% and then want to restrict privileges to definite database which matches this pattern then you must revoke ALL to this pattern, grant ALL to each separate database (and/or use less wide pattern groups which does not match the database to be restricted) and USAGE to the database in interest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic problem

There is no such thing as `GRANT USAGE` at the database level.

Logically, `GRANT USAGE` indicates the ability to login (authenticate) and nothing more. This is implemented in `mysql.user` holding login information and all global privileges set to `'N'`. Please see my old post from April 12, 2012 [Cannot GRANT privileges as root](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/cannot-grant-privileges-as-root/16441#16441) for how `mysql.user` appears in all versions of MySQL past and present. The same would apply to MariaDB.

### PROPOSED SOLUTION

You would have to delete the row from `mysql.db` table.

```
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE host='server' AND user='db' AND db='db_%';
```

Then issue a separate grant for all databases that have `db_` but exclude `db_6`

The following bash script will do that for you

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=whateverpassword
MYSQL_AUTH="-hlocalhost -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"

GRANTS_SQL=reshape_grants.sql

echo "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE host='server' AND user='db' AND db='db_%';" > ${GRANTS_SQL}
echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" >> ${GRANTS_SQL}

SQL="SELECT schema_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE schema_name LIKE 'db_%' AND schema_name <> 'db_6'"
DBLIST=`mysql ${MYSQL_AUTH} -ANe"${SQL}"`
for DB in ${DBLIST}
do
    echo "GRANT ALL ON ${DB}.* TO 'user'@'server';" >> ${GRANT_SQL}
done
echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" >> ${GRANTS_SQL}
```

This will create the grants file to do the following

1. Remove all database-level grants for databases starting with `db_`
2. Grant `'user'@'server'` full access to all `db_` databases other than `db_6`

Look at the contents to make sure

```
cat ${GRANTS_SQL}
```

Comment: This is something I thought about, but the number of databases evolves and the application does not manage, as the time of writing, the part to set PERMISSION on the applicative user when a new database is created. Perhaps this is the only real and good solution.